# Azure MobileApp Custom Authentication VS Asp.Net Identity

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api, azure-mobile-services

Microsoft claims to provide OOB functionality for custom authentication. I started using this library, I am surprised that only feature available from this library is to generate token. Thats all! I believe Default template for Web API Asp.Net Identity is a better implementation and provides complete functionality.

Mobile App has to be something better than close to metal Web API. Am I missing something here, could you please show me the right direction?

References:
http://www.newventuresoftware.com/blog/custom-authentication-with-azure-mobile-apps/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Azure Mobile Apps provides a turnkey solution, where by simply configuring the identity providers you want to support (e.g. Azure Active Directory, Microsoft Account, Facebook, Google, etc.) you can enable authentication.

This document provides an overview, as well as links to details and technical resources:

https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-auth/